# Python Output Length

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, sqlite, python-3.x

I'm attempting to output my database table data, which works aside from long table rows.  The columns need to be as large as the longest database row.  I'm having trouble implementing a calculation to correctly output the table proportionally instead of a huge mess when long rows are outputted (without using a third party library e.g. [Print results in MySQL format with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865483/print-results-in-mysql-format-with-python)).  Please let me know if you need more information.

Database connection:

```
connection = sqlite3.connect("test_.db")
c = connection.cursor()

 c.execute("SELECT * FROM MyTable")
          results = c.fetchall()
          formatResults(results)
```

Table formatting:

```
def formatResults(x):
    try: 
          widths = []
          columns = []
          tavnit = '|'
          separator = '+' 

          for cd in c.description:
                widths.append(max(cd[2], len(cd[0])))
                columns.append(cd[0])

          for w in widths:
                tavnit += " %-"+"%ss |" % (w,)
                separator += '-'*w + '--+'

          print(separator)
          print(tavnit % tuple(columns))
          print(separator)
          for row in x:
              print(tavnit % row)
          print(separator)
          print ""
    except:
        showMainMenu()
        pass
```

Output problem example:

```
+------+------+---------+
| Date | Name | LinkOrFile |
+------+------+---------+
| 03-17-2016 | hi.com | Locky |
| 03-18-2016 | thisisitsqq.com | None    |
| 03-19-2016 | http://ohiyoungbuyff.com\69.exe?1 | None    |
| 03-20-2016 | http://thisisitsqq..com\69.exe?1 | None    |
| 03-21-2016 | %Temp%\zgHRNzy\69.exe | None    |
| 03-22-2016 |      | None    |
| 03-23-2016 | E52219D0DA33FDD856B2433D79D71AD6 | Downloader |
| 03-24-2016 | microsoft.com | None    |
| 03-25-2016 | 89.248.166.132 | None    |
| 03-26-2016 | http://89.248.166.131/55KB5js9dwPtx4= | None    |
```

Comment: what exactly is the problem you are facing?

Comment: Did you print the output of the variable widths? Does it contain the length of the longest value per column?

Comment: I'm not sure how I'd go about that.

Comment: In `formatResults` after first loop, add line `print widths`

Comment: Ok, I get:  [4]
[4, 4]
[4, 4, 7]

Comment: Any ideas on what to do next would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If your main problem is making column widths consistent across all the lines, this python package could do the job: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tabulate

Below you find a very simple example of a possible formatting approach.
The key point is to find the largest length of each column and then use `format` method of the string object:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import random
import string
from operator import itemgetter


def randomString(minLen = 1, maxLen = 10):
    """ Random string of length between 1 and 10 """
    l = random.randint(minLen, maxLen)
    return ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits) for _ in range(l))

COLUMNS = 4

def randomTable():
    table = []
    for i in range(10):
        table.append( [randomString() for j in range(COLUMNS)] )
    return table

def findMaxColumnLengs(table):
    """ Returns tuple of max column lengs """
    maxLens = [0] * COLUMNS
    for l in table:
        lens = [len(s) for s in l]
        maxLens = [max(maxLens[e[0]], e[1]) for e in enumerate(lens)]

    return maxLens



if __name__ == '__main__':
    ll = randomTable()

    ml = findMaxColumnLengs(ll)

    # tuple of formatting statements, see format docs
    formatStrings = ["{:<%s}" % str(m) for m in ml ]
    fmtStr = "|".join(formatStrings)

    print "=================================="
    for l in ll:
        print l
    print "=================================="
    for l in ll:
        print fmtStr.format(*l)
```

This prints the initial table packed in the list of lists and the formatted output.

```
==================================
['2U7Q', 'DZK8Z5XT', '7ZI0W', 'A9SH3V3U']
['P7SOY3RSZ1', 'X', 'Z2W', 'KF6']
['NO8IEY9A', '4FVGQHG', 'UGMJ', 'TT02X']
['9S43YM', 'JCUT0', 'W', 'KB']
['P43T', 'QG', '0VT9OZ0W', 'PF91F']
['2TEQG0H6A6', 'A4A', '4NZERXV', '6KMV22WVP0']
['JXOT', 'AK7', 'FNKUEL', 'P59DKB8']
['BTHJ', 'XVLZZ1Q3H', 'NQM16', 'IZBAF']
['G0EF21S', 'A0G', '8K9', 'RGOJJYH2P9']
['IJ', 'SRKL8TXXI', 'R', 'PSUZRR4LR']
==================================
2U7Q      |DZK8Z5XT |7ZI0W   |A9SH3V3U  
P7SOY3RSZ1|X        |Z2W     |KF6       
NO8IEY9A  |4FVGQHG  |UGMJ    |TT02X     
9S43YM    |JCUT0    |W       |KB        
P43T      |QG       |0VT9OZ0W|PF91F     
2TEQG0H6A6|A4A      |4NZERXV |6KMV22WVP0
JXOT      |AK7      |FNKUEL  |P59DKB8   
BTHJ      |XVLZZ1Q3H|NQM16   |IZBAF     
G0EF21S   |A0G      |8K9     |RGOJJYH2P9
IJ        |SRKL8TXXI|R       |PSUZRR4LR
```

Comment: he doesnt want to use a package, as his question mentions.

Comment: Yes, I want to do this without a package.

Comment: Sorry, I have overlooked that. I've added an example

Answer (score 0):

The code that you used is for MySQL. The critical part is the line `widths.append(max(cd[2], len(cd[0])))` where `cd[2]` gives the length of the longest data in that column. This works for MySQLdb.

However, you are using sqlite3, for which the value `cd[2]` is set to `None`:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.description

Thus, you will need to replace the following logic:

```
 for cd in c.description:
                widths.append(max(cd[2], len(cd[0])))
                columns.append(cd[0])
```

with your own. The rest of the code should be fine as long as `widths` is computed correctly.

The easiest way to get the `widths` variable correctly, would be to traverse through each row of the result and find out the max width of each column, then append it to `widths`. This is just some *pseudo code*:

```
for cd in c.description:
   columns.append(cd[0])  # Get column headers

widths = [0] * len(c.description)   # Initialize to number of columns.
for row in x:
  for i in range(len(row)):  # This assumes that row is an iterable, like list
    v = row[i]  # Take value of ith column
    widths[i] = max(len(v), widths[i]) # Compare length of current value with value already stored
```

At the end of this, `widths` should contain the maximum length of each column.

Comment: Ok, how would I replace that logic that you mentioned?  Could you provide a sample please?

Comment: I'm not sure how I'd go about this.

Comment: This works but it does not return single-value queries such as Count(*).  Any ideas on that one?

Comment: May have to do with the way `widths` is initialized. See edit.

Comment: The Count(*) functions and large query results do not show up.