# How can I see the output in python as like SQL table format

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, format

The code and output which I have written is attached below..
FInd it in above images.

```
    import psycopg2
    conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='news' user='postgres'")
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute(
        "SELECT * FROM authors")
    results = cursor.fetchall()
    print (results)
    conn.close
```

The code and output:

[image]

The output format what I want:

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865483/print-results-in-mysql-format-with-python 
I'd look at the second answer here.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the library `pandas` for this, it has convenient methods to show data and does the alignment of columns for you.

Here is a small sample:

```
import pandas as pd
print(pd.DataFrame([(1,2,3), (1,2,3)], columns=['a', 'b', 'c']))
```

Leads to the output

```
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
1  1  2  3
```

And in your case, you would want to use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(results, columns=['name', 'description', 'id'])
```

I just guessed the column names...

Comment: Nothing was mentioned about pandas, so why bring it up?

Comment: Because it does the job.

Comment: You can do the job 100 other ways, too, why not list them all? :)